# Input textbox data into array of objects

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object

I am using the module to declare the public class patient across all forms of my program. What do I have to do in order to input data into the array from three text boxes. One for Names, Heights, and Weights. Thanks

```
Public Module Module1
Public PatientCount As Integer = 0

Public Class Patient

    Public Property Name As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Height As Decimal = 0

    Public Property Weight As Decimal = 0

End Class
End Module


Dim patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)
```

For displaying patients in listbox

```
    For Each p As Module1.Patient In Patients
        lstPatients.Items.Add(p.Name)
    Next
```

CURRENT CODE:
MODULE

```
Public Module Module1
Public PatientCount As Integer = 0
Public Patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)

Public Class Patient

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Height As Decimal

    Public Property Weight As Decimal

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal height As Decimal, ByVal weight As Decimal)
        name = _Name
        weight = _Weight
        height = _Height
    End Sub
End Class
End Module
```

FORM 2 (Entry of Data)

```
Public Class Form2


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPatient.Click

    patients.Add(New Patient(txtName.Text, CDec(txtHeight.Text), CDec(txtWeight.Text)))

    PatientCount = PatientCount + 1
    Label1.Text = PatientCount

End Sub
End Class
```

FORM 3 (Listing of Data)
    Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each p As Patient In Patients
        lstPatients.Items.Add("Name: " & p.Name)
        lstPatients.Items.Add("Weight: " & p.Weight)
        lstPatients.Items.Add("Height: " & p.Height)
        lstPatients.Items.Add("___________")
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I wouldn't store the textboxes on an array, how is the index of an array related to a name or height or weight at all? You could use a `UserControl` which includes all three TextBoxes. Then you can create one UC for every Patient in the list. If you provide meaningful (public) properties like `Name` there your code becomes much more redable and maintainable. This `Name` property would simply get or set the appropriate `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: It is for a school project, I need to allow the user to enter patient data through a textbox and later display it. So how do I go about storing the user entered data from the textbox into the array so I can display it.

Comment: create a Patient object - you have the class, store the form data into it, then add the new Patient to the `List(Of Patient)`.  The Pateient properties are going to work just like regular GUI ones

Comment: how do I actually add new Patients to the List(Of Patient)? In the click event handler of the enter patient button what code would go there to enter that data into the patient object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the data of an x number of patients, you could have this code in a `button-clicked` event handler.

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()Handles BtnOk.Click()
    patients.Add(New Module1.Patient(txtName.Text, CDec(txtHeight.Text), CDec(txtWeight.text))
End Sub
```

And then add this to your `Patient` class:

```
Public Module Module1

Public Class Patient

    Public Property Name As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Height As Decimal = 0

    Public Property Weight As Decimal = 0

    Public Sub New(_name as String, _height as decimal, _weight as decimal)
        Name = _name
        Weight = _weight
        Height = _height
    End Sub
End Class
End Module


Dim patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)
```

With this, you will create a list of patients every time the btnOk is pressed, and you can easily access any patient and their data.

To put the data in a listbox:

```
Private Sub BTNLIST_Click()Handles BTNLIST.Click
    For Each p As Patient in patients
        lstbox.Items.Add("Name: " & p.Name)
        lstbox.Items.Add("Weight: " & p.Weight)
        lstbox.Items.Add("Height: " & p.Height)
        lstbox.Items.Add("___________")
    Next
End Sub
```

**OPTIONAL**

You could even create a `PatientList` Class to help you further (but remove the patients List). You could use the `PatientList` class to add helpful functions, such as finding a patient by name or height.:

```
Public Class PatientList

    Public List(Of Patient) Patients = New List(Of Patient)

    Public ReadOnly Property PatientCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return Patients.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub AddPatientToList(name as String, height as decimal, weight as decimal)
        Patients.Add(New Patient(name, height, weight)
    End Sub
End Class

Dim patients as PatientList
```

Then add this in your button_click Handler:

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()Handles BtnOk.Click()
        patients.AddPatientToList(New Module1.Patient(txtName.Text, CDec(txtHeight.Text), CDec(txtWeight.text))
    End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: do you know why I could be receiving the "is not part of System.Array" error using the second answer?

Comment: Idk...it might have to do with the parenthesis...have you tried the other answers? Personally, I think having a `New()` subfunction, as suggested by me and tinstaafl, is much more effective because you only need one line of code to initialize the `Patient` object, as compared to 3 or more. (And there's much less clutter if you develop a big program)

Comment: Ok thankyou, I'll try your answer. Gandy's just looked the most simple

Comment: Ok, I understand. All I really added was the Initializer for the `Patient` object (`Public Sub New()`), and the code for the `Button_Clicked` Event. The bottom portion was just a suggestion (and me getting carried away thinking about designing a big interface :)), so you could just ignore that.

Comment: Personally, in the long run, I think mine or @tinstaafl 's would be better. You're initializing a class, and adding properties to it via the initialization. So if you create a big application that has a class with _many_ properties (like I did when I created an `animation` class for a simulation software for a major corporation), you can initialize everything with the `New()` subfunction of the object, and won't have to write 10 lines just to set all the properties individually.

Comment: The Patient list will come in handy for me as the project also requires me to find patients with matching weights and search for patients with a binary search method

Comment: Yes, I added the code to the button clicked event handler and the error went away, however there is another one to do with the list. 'AddPatientToList' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of HSC_Major_Project_1.Module1.Patient)'"

Comment: If want you call `AddPatientToList()`, you'll have to add the `PatientList` class under the optional part. If you don't add that class, just call `patients.Add()` (Make sure, if you use the `PatientList` class, to use `Dim patients as PatientList` instead of `Dim patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)`)

Comment: ok the error is gone, now all I want to do is display the data entered in a listbox so I can enter test data and ensure it all works properly. I know the code to list a simple array in a listbox but how do I display the this patient object in the listbox?

Comment: in the original question I added the code I am using to display the patients but when I click nothing happens. What is wrong with that loop? Also I usually do figure stuff like this on my own by playing around with the code but this new Patient list array is new to me so I'm having some trouble with it

Comment: Thanks :), however when it lists it does not list any of my data but blanks. Name it has a blank and for height and weight it just has 0

Comment: I've haven't been working on my project recently but I am now so I will try it, thanks for the help

Comment: I just added the _ however the patients are still blank. I don't think the array thay is displayed is getting any input from the user entry in textboxes

Comment: I figured out that the height and weight are just returning 0, while the name is returning a blank if that helps. could this be a problem with the code that takes the user input from the textboxes then stores in the list?

Comment: I put in a breakpoint and when I enter p.Name into the Watch window, it returns p.Name is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Okay, try changing this line `Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal height As Decimal, ByVal weight As Decimal)` to `Public Sub New(ByVal _name As String, ByVal _height As Decimal, ByVal _weight As Decimal)`

Comment: thanks that fixed everything, now what is the exact name for this group I am using to store the patient data in. Is it an array of some sort?

Comment: The `Patients` object is a `list`, which is very similar to an array. Glad I was able to help. Feel free to mark it as an answer if everything's answered :) (This will help other users with similar questions too) Btw, you may want to delete some of these comments, and remove the code you just added (since it was added for me to see)

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help, but I do have one more question. If I were to search within the list, would it be the same as searching a simple array such as a binary search. Also is sorting an object list  the same as sorting in a simple array?

Comment: Because that is the next part of my assignment which I would be able to do simply myself however I am kind of unfamiliar with how object lists work

Comment: Yes, a list is pretty similar to an array. Microsoft would have help on lists, and lists have a `Sort()` function just like arrays, and lists also have `BinarySearch` and `Find` functions. Just play around with them; they are pretty easy to learn. Good luck with your project! If you ever need help, feel free to message me or something here on SO. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, how do I message people on here, is there such an option?

Comment: @Marcel, I don't think there's such an option ( I couldn't find anything.) However, you could just post a comment on any of my answers or questions and I'd see it. Then we could setup a chat room if you wanted.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, by the way I managed to bubble sort the three separate arrays so I am now using them instead of the list.

Comment: can you please help out on my newest question? there is probably a simple answer but I can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a New constructor that takes the 3 values for the properties.

```
Public Module Module1
Public PatientCount As Integer = 0

Public Class Patient

    Public Property Name As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Height As Decimal = 0

    Public Property Weight As Decimal = 0

    Public Sub New(_name As String, _height As Decimal, _weight As Decimal)
        Name = _name
        Height = _height
        Weight = _weight
    End Sub

End Class
End Module


Dim patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)
```

Assuming you've validated the input from the textboxes and converted them to variables(NewName, NewHeight, NewWeight), you would add a new patient something like this:

```
patients.Add(New Patient(NewName,NewHeight,NewWeight))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll try it along with the other answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a patient then you need to create an instance of one and set it properties with the textboxes of whatever form your using.  Then add the new patient to the list of patients, so something like this.

```
Dim patient as new Patient()
patient.Name = txtName.Text()
patient.Height = txtHeight.Text()
patient.Weight = txtWeight.Text()

patients.Add(patient)
```

Comment: using your code returns the error Name, Height, Weight, is not a member of System.Array? Thanks